# Styling and SVG circle inside a <use> without using the * symbol?

Tags: css, svg

I'm using the `<use>` element to show duplicate SVG's. My problem is I want to style a specific part of the SVG, currently I'm doing: `.spinner svg * {...}`, I'm using the catch-all * because I cannot find the element I should be focusing.

I've tried .spinner `svg circle {...}` and all other combinations but nothing is working.

If the styling is working than the inner circle will fill pink.

So for clarity, the .spinner svg * { ... } works but because I want to add more to this SVG, I can no longer use it, and want to target the circle element directly. How may I do this?

```css
.spinner
{
    display: inline-block;

    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;

    -webkit-animation: container 1568ms linear infinite;
            animation: container 1568ms linear infinite;
}

.spinner svg
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-animation: svg-spin 5332ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) infinite;
            animation: svg-spin 5332ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) infinite;

    stroke: #fd75c5;
}

.spinner svg *
{
    transition: stroke 133ms linear;
    -webkit-animation: circle-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) infinite;
            animation: circle-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) infinite;

    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: .2rem;

    fill: pink;
}


























@-webkit-keyframes container
{
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes container
{
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes svg-spin
{
    12.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
                transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    25%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
                transform: rotate(270deg);
    }

    37.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
                transform: rotate(405deg);
    }

    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
                transform: rotate(540deg);
    }

    62.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
                transform: rotate(675deg);
    }

    75%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
                transform: rotate(810deg);
    }

    87.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
                transform: rotate(945deg);
    }

    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
                transform: rotate(1080deg);
    }
}

@keyframes svg-spin
{
    12.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
                transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    25%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
                transform: rotate(270deg);
    }

    37.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
                transform: rotate(405deg);
    }

    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
                transform: rotate(540deg);
    }

    62.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
                transform: rotate(675deg);
    }

    75%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
                transform: rotate(810deg);
    }

    87.5%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
                transform: rotate(945deg);
    }

    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
                transform: rotate(1080deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-spin
{
    0%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 5 120;
        stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    }

    50%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 100 25;
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    }

    100%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 5 120;
        stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    }
}

@keyframes circle-spin
{
    0%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 5 120;
        stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    }

    50%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 100 25;
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    }

    100%
    {
        stroke-dasharray: 5 120;
        stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
 <defs>
  <symbol id="loader" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" />
  </symbol>
 </defs>
</svg>



<div class="spinner">
 <svg><use xlink:href="#loader"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Clone the elements you want instead of using use in a way its not designed to support.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the circle via the SVG that references it.  You can think of it that as the symbol doesn't exist under `<div class="spinner"><use>` so you can't style it that way.

What you could do is style is via the symbol. For example:

```
#loader circle {
  fill: pink;
}
```

But that will change every reference to `#loader`.  If you need to have several different spinners each styled differently, then you need to have separate copies of the spinner symbol.